# How to work with more than one output parameter in single stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a SP with an Output parameter that looks like:
`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Name] @VarName decimal(18,2) OUTPUT as` ...

I call that procedure from vb.net to get the value for calculations. My problem is: I have 8 SP's with the following structure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Name] @VarName decimal(18,2) OUTPUT as ...
CREATE TABLE @TempTable
Begin
Select ...
End
SET @VarName = Result
```

But the TempTable is always the same. No I am looking for a way to get all 8 values with only one stored procedure. My idea:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Name] @VarName decimal(18,2) OUTPUT as ...
CREATE TABLE @TempTable
---Get first value
Begin
Select ...
End
SET @VarName1 = Result
---Get second value
Begin
Select ...
End
SET @VarName2 = Result
...
```

How do i have to rewrite the line: `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Name] @VarName decimal(18,2) OUTPUT` ir can I even work with an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single stored procedure with all your queries in it. Following will return a single row result set with eight fields and you can grab them from your code using the specific filed name or index.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Name] 
  @VarName decimal(18,2) 
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @VarName1 Datatype, @VarName2 Datatype, ...@VarName8 Datatype

    SELECT @VarName1 = yourCol
    FROM --First query

    SELECT @VarName2 = yourCol
    FROM --Second query
    ...

    SELECT @VarName8 = yourCol
    FROM --Eighth query

    --Finally Select all the variables
    SELECT @VarName1 Col1, @VarName2 Col2, ...,@VarName8 Col8
END
```

OR if you are looking to return results of your all 8 queries, that is also possible. Simply do your select queries in a single stored procedure and grab the `DATASET` from your code and you can access individual table using zero based Index (ex `DataTable1 = YourDataSet.Tables[0]`)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. So i reckon I will use the Dataset solution. I thought there would be maybe a solution where i can put all 8 values into an outputparameter(array) and call it with something like: cmd.Parameters.Add("@Varname[1]",SqlDbType.Int).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;

Comment: Well, you can use one or many [out put parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx) in a single stored procedure and access them but in my opinion, it is easy to return a single query and take them without declaring 8 output parameters.